# how to use struts2 tag to traversal a Map<Object,String> in jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2

How to use Struts2 tag to traversal a `Map<Course,String>` in JSP.
`Course` is a class. It has three attributes. They are `String coursename`, `int courseid`, `String courseType`. I use Struts2 in my project. The Action returns the `Map<Course,String>` to JSP.
And I use

```
<s:iterator value="cmap" status="st">
  <tr><td>
    <s:iterator value='key'><s:property value="key.coursename"/></s:iterator> </td>
   <td><s:property value='value'></s:property></td></tr>
</s:iterator>
```

It can print the right String value in JSP. But it cannot print the Course Type data!
How to solve it? I am a novice.

Comment: Post your action code, I'm sure you have object in it that is accessible pretty to iterate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need second iterator to get `Course` data. Just use `key` to get your values.

```
<s:iterator value="cmap">
  <tr>
    <td><s:property value="key.coursename"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="value"/></td>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

BTW a map with a key which is custom object is very annoying thing.

Comment: Because usually the key "is small" and the referred object "is big". You use an entire object as key, and a String (containing what?) as value :)

Comment: @Ryan: Because of the equals and hash -> `if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))`.