# Struts2: Displaying text/huge file in textarea or frame

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a huge content of data which is stored in a data-structure (TreeMap) in the backend and I need to display that in my UI which should be based on struts2.

Any idea on how to display the content of the Map in the struts2 front end screen?

In backend I will be using a for loop to iterate through each record of the map and need to display it line by line in the front end. I don't think that I can use textarea for this. Whether there is any feature available in struts2 to print it line by line in the front end by reading it from backend. I am totally new to struts and It will be great if I could get any suggestions. Please let me know in case if any clarification is needed.

Comment: *"I don't think that I can use textarea for this."*  Why do you think that?  *"Thanks, Bala"*  Sigs. are noise.  Leave them out of posts.  BTW - What is the point of displaying an 'huge' amount of text in a web page?  Do you expect that the user will sit there and carefully read it line by line?  If not, then perhaps other strategies should be used in order to filter the data down to the essentials.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - My requirement is different. I am building a web based tool and i need to display an huge amount of data. Thanks for pointing out the sign I will remove it from my next post. Please dont down vote. I just joined SO.

Comment: *"My requirement is different."*  Different to what? *"I am building a web based tool and i need to display an huge amount of data."*  Umm.. that much was obvious from before I first commented.  Was there a point to repeating it?  What was that point?

Comment: "Was there a point to repeating it? What was that point?" - I am just trying to answer your question Andrew. "Different to what?" - it is different from a normal website. It is a simple tool for my personal use.

Comment: @sbala_20 You should clarify the question to make it clear to understand, supply it with the code you wrote, highlight the problems you stuck on, explain what did you try to resolve them, what happened, what errors did you get, and so on, so people get interesting to help you. Without it your question is only a wall of text.

Comment: @Roman C - understood. Will try to do it from my next post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the map using an iterator and print the values on the screen like you can find out from this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401026/how-to-use-struts2-tag-to-traversal-a-mapobject-string-in-jsp).

Also, you should know that it does not matter that much how big it is your TreeMap because the rendering of the JSP will happen on the **server side**.

**EDIT** You need to pass only the Map to the JSP. That means you only need to put **getter** and **setter** for the Map in the Action Class. In the JSP you will use the tag `<s:iterate value="myTreeMap">` like you can see in the link that i put above.

Comment: Can't agree with your second statement - a huge response will cause problems on the server side as much as it does on the client side

Comment: @DaveHowes Of course that an incredibly huge response can cause problems...needless to say that. What I wanted to point out was that the front end won't have nothing to do but to display the output and not to perform the processing (e.g. a loop). As you can see he repeated several times "backend" and "frontend". I wanted to make sure he knows this (I didn't know it at the very beginning). I think that you could have understood my intention better...

Comment: @Setila - My understanding - I need to iterate through the Map in the java action class and pass each iteration in to the iterator in the jsp page. Jsp page will print the data until the iteration is over.Is that rite?

Comment: @sbala_20 No, you don't have to do this, just pass the map. I edited the answear and you should really look at the other question on SO to see an example.

Answer (score 0):

there can be diferent solutin to display data on frontend => table, li's, div's, input's, whatever..
and also in jsp you'll need a loop to iterate through elements, take a look at :

- Struts [iterator](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/iterator.html)
- JSTL [forEach tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm)